# Elementary reference for Borel-Moore/locally finite homology

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, sheaf-cohomology

There is a homology theory called "Borel-Moore" or "locally finite" homology, which can either be constructed by using locally-finite chains or by more advanced sheaf-theoretic methods. Here are two useful facts about it:

1. If $X$ is locally compact and $\tilde X$ is a reasonable compactification, then $H^{lf}(X) \cong H(X, \tilde X \setminus X)$ agrees with the ordinary homology relative to infinity.
2. If $X$ is an orientable manifold with boundary (maybe weaker hypotheses suffice), not necessarily closed, then $H^{lf}_k(X)$ is dual to $H_{n-k}(X, \partial X)$.

Either of these results might be stated slightly wrong, which is partially what my question is about.

I am looking for a reference that constructs $H^{lf}$ and proves one or both of these results, but using less technical machinery than last chapter of Bredon's *Sheaf Theory* (which I think has what I want, but I don't know enough sheaf theory to understand it.) Hatcher only mentions $H^{lf}$ in an exercise, and Bredon's *Topology and Geometry* doesn't discuss it at all.

I see that there are some related questions ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160295/worked-out-examples-in-borel-moore-homology) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249342/two-points-of-view-about-borel-moore-homology)) that suggest there are no good references, so maybe this is a lost cause, but I notice neither mentions the duality property (2).

Comment: For constant coefficients the standard reference is Massey "Homology and cohomology theory". As you say, the reference for local coefficients is Bredon's "Sheaf theory".

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but the appendix to Fulton's "Young Tableaux" takes an elementary approach by defining $H_*^{BM}(X)$ to be $H^*(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^n - X)[n]$ where $X \to \mathbb R^n$ is a closed embedding.   You can prove that this is independent of the choice of embedding.  It seems likely that you can then prove $(1)$ and $(2)$ directly using Alexander/Lefschetz duality.

Comment: Massey wrote down a bunch of stuff in his book *Homology and Cohomology Theory*. He doesn't call it Borel-Moore, but he cites their paper and constructs some kind of locally-finite cohomology. I don't know how much he does.